# Arduino adc wrong random values

Tags: arduino

i am using arduino uno , atmega328.
on analogRead on the analog pin A0 returns 0 when it is grounded, and with HIGH signal from another pin it returns some value around 1000. But when i connect it to a sensor which gives out around 26 mV it returns random values ... 
YYY
My code is very basic, uses analogRead and display it in serial monitor.

Comment: How "random"?  Can you give examples?  How do you know your sensor outputs 26mV?  How noisy is it?  Have you tried connecting a known voltage source (e.g. the output of a potential divider)?

Comment: the sensor is lm35 temperature sensor, sorry tat was 260mV with some fluctuations of  +-10 mv .

Comment: 80
28
12
46
30
29
0
0
44
0
7
0
0
0
83
36
88
22
0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signal with fluctuations of 10mV is not random. The flucatuations are called [noise.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_noise) The standard approach is to add a low pass filter in hardware or software. Since you have a controller anyway I would go for software based low pass filtering. A simple and computational cheap but effective low pass filter is an exponential filter, also known as [exponential moving average.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)

Comment: tyty . 
The fault was mine, i used the arduino soft version 1.0.3, i updated it , now its working fine.